# Laptop sound from mobile speakers

Tags: laptop, audio, bluetooth

How to connect laptop to my nokia 5800 to hear laptop sound in mobile speakers?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that your phone has no Line-In connection, I don't see how it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't use your mobile speaker as PC or laptop speaker. You only can use your laptop or PC speaker as Nokia N82 external speaker.