# How to connect laptop to my nokia

Tags: bluetooth

How to connect laptop to my nokia e71 to hear laptop sound in mobile speakers using bluetooth?

Comment: Similar questions here: http://superuser.com/questions/76416/laptop-sound-from-mobile-speakers and http://superuser.com/questions/76550/redirect-audio-from-laptop-to-mobile.

Answer (score 2):

turn on your laptop and e71 bluetooth ..
search with the laptop bluetooth and double click on your mobile bluetooth name (after the search it will appear of course )

enter any number in your mobile ...and then the same number on your laptop ...finish (connected) ^_^

Comment: That simply creates a Bluetooth pairing.  How do you then pipe the audio from the laptop to the handset's speakers?

Comment: @ Kez... i'll search more about it..

Comment: @zubair... i guess you will have to use Nokia PC suite  in order to get your laptop connect through your phone...did you install it?!